# Jquery ui accordion on table in asp.net mvc View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

i have to implement jquery ui accordion and sortable in asp.net mvc dynamically generated table rows. i have implemented sortable and its working fine but how can i impelement accordion to table tbody.

```
        <table >    
    <tbody id="rowAccordion">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr class="rowSort">
                    <td style="width: 200px;">
                        <h3>
                            <a href="#">@item.PageTitle</a>
                        </h3>
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                Discription
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }  
</tbody> 
</table>

<script>
    $(function () { $("#rowAccordion").accordion(); }); 

    $("#rowAccordion").sortable();
</script>
```

Comment: Did you have success?

Answer (score 1):

Use the option "header" using the column that you want to appear as the header.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rowAccordion").accordion({header: 'YOUR COLUMN SELECTOR HERE' });
});
```

hth